# Javascript, Eventhandler for any checkbox in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to check how many checkboxes are checked in my form. This should be controlled on every click on a checkbox. At the moment i call the function if a special checkbox is changed, but i want to check the value by change on every checkbox.

```
  $('#checkboxname').change(function(){
        var $b = $('input[type=checkbox]');
        console.info("EE " + $b.filter(':checked').length);   // WORKS !!!
  });
```

Can you please tell me whats the problem with this code.
Thanks a lot

Comment: I am really not sure what you are asking. Sorry.

Comment: Why don't you just listen to all the changes on the form with a `$('.formId input[type=checkbox]').change(...)` instead?

Comment: Questions asking for code **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.**

Comment: You noted in your code that it *"`// WORKS !!!`"*. What problem are you having?

Answer (score 2):

> i want to check the value by change on every checkbox.

so just target every checkbox ?

```
var boxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');

boxes.on('change', function(){
    console.info("EE " + boxes.filter(':checked').length);   // WORKS !!!
});
```